# Trying to compare two ints

Tags: java, int, comparison-operators

This is my first time asking a question and I have tried to search the existing threads first.  My program is meant to ask the user to enter a 5-digit number and it will check to see if it is a palindrome by reversing the number and then comparing the original number to the reverse.  I also put in some verification steps there to reject the number if it is longer or shorter than 5 digits.  Everything seems to work until it gets to the part comparing the original number and the reversed number.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindromes {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n, reverse = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a 5-digit integer to see if it is a palindrome.");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();
        int length = String.valueOf(n).length();
        while (length > 5 || length < 5) {
            System.out.println("Error: integer must be 5 digits in length.");
            System.out.println("Enter a 5-digit integer.");
            n = in.nextInt();
            length = String.valueOf(n).length();
        }
        while (length == 5 && n != 0) {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("Reversed number is: " + reverse);
        if (n == reverse) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! Your number is a palindrome!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry.  Your number isn't a palindrome.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Everything seems to work until it gets to the part comparing the original number and the reversed number." So in what way doesn't that work? Can you give a concrete example of what *does* happen vs what you *expect* to happen? Hint: you've just written a loop that will only terminate when `n` is 0. You're modifying `n` in the loop. You're then comparing `n` with `reverse`... (You might want to take a copy of the original number...)

Comment: This is a good time to polish your debugging skills. Put some breakpoints or `println` statements before, inside and after your loop and watch what happens. Debugging is an important skill to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at what you are doing here!

```
while (length == 5 && n != 0) {
    reverse = reverse * 10;
    reverse = reverse + n % 10;
    n = n / 10; // <----- You are changing "n"!
}
```

Which means that after the loop, `n` will no longer be the same `n` that the user entered.

To fix this, copy `n` to another variable and modify that instead.

```
int temp = n;
while (length == 5 && temp != 0) {
    reverse = reverse * 10;
    reverse = reverse + temp % 10;
    temp = temp / 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, guys.  So when I ran the code as I first posted it, the validation check for the number length worked, but comparing n == result didn't.  Thank you, Sweeper, for reminding me n changed. I modified the length check so that it looks like this:

Comment: int temp = n;
        int length = String.valueOf(temp).length();
        while (length > 5 || length < 5) {
            System.out.println("Error: integer must be 5 digits in length.");
            System.out.println("Enter a 5-digit integer.");
            n = in.nextInt();
            length = n;
            length = String.valueOf(temp).length();
        }
        while (length == 5 && temp != 0) {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to format that.  Basically, Sweeper correctly pointed out that at the comparison between n and reverse, I was no longer comparing the original n.  So I corrected it by passing n through the temp variable, but now the validation check for length doesn't work --if you type in a three digit number it correctly flags but doesn't recognize a 5 digit number after.  But the code runs correctly if you start with a 5 digit number.

Comment: Thanks again, Sweeper! After I fixed the n and reverse comparison by adding the temp variable, I realized I had to clean up the length validation a bit to be consistent with using temp instead of n to check the length. But everything works now.

Answer (score 3):

it's more easy to convert the number to an array and reverse it instead of calculating it:

```
let reverseNumber = parseInt(12345.toString().split("").reverse().join());
```

Comment: I know, but we aren't allowed to use arrays in this class until the instructor covers it in class.